Mern stack authorization using access token along with a refresh token stored in a cookie
I am trying to intercept responses gotten from my node express server using axios interceptors. The goal of this is to spot whenvever i get a 403 error response status as a result of my access token being expired and have my interceptor make a request to my backend to generate a new access token. The interceptor does this by sending a refresh token in form of a cookie which will be validated and checked in the backend as well.
My problem is that since my backend also returns a status code of 403 whenever the refresh token expires, the interceptor keeps making endless request to my server.
Should i just change the status code returned in times of expired refresh tokens?? or is there a way i could stop the endless loop of requests.
Here is my configuration for the interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  async (error) => {
    const originalConfig = error.config;
    if (error.response) {
      if (error.response.status === 403 && !originalConfig?._retry) {
        originalConfig._retry = true;
        try {
          // call refresh token endpoint;
          const { data } = await axios.post(
            `${import.meta.env.VITE_GENERAL_API_ENDPOINT}auth/generate-token`,
            {},
            { withCredentials: true }
          );
          const { token } = data;
          originalConfig.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
          axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
          return axios(originalConfig);
        } catch (refreshError) {
          console.error("Failed to refresh token:", refreshError);
          // Throw an error to stop further execution or handle as appropriate
          return Promise.reject(refreshError);
        }
      }
    }
    // throw error;
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

Here is the middleware that checks and validates the refresh token in my node server;
exports.refreshTokenCheck = asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const refreshToken = req.cookies["refresh_token"];
  console.log(refreshToken);
  if (!refreshToken) {
    console.log(
      "we tried generating a new access token but ran into this error because there is no token"
    );
    return next(new CustomError("Unauthorized", 401));
  }
  try {
    //verify refresh token
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(
      refreshToken,
      process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET_KEY
    );
    // if (!decodedToken) {
    //   return next(new CustomError("Unauthorized", 401));
    // }
    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decodedToken.id }).populate(
      "subscriptions.plan"
    );
    if (!user) {
      return next(new CustomError("User not found", 404));
    }
    req.user = user;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    if (
      error.name === "TokenExpiredError" ||
      error.name === "JsonWebTokenError" ||
      error.name === "NotBeforeError"
    ) {
      console.log(
        "we tried generating a new access token but ran into this error"
      );
      return next(new CustomError("Forbidden", 403));
    }
    next(error);
  }
});

